# How to install lsb_release in opensuse 13.2?

Tags: package-management, opensuse

I want to know the command through which I can install lsb_release in opensuse 13.2 while using OpenSUSE 13.2 through a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I've checked on my current system:

```
$ dpkg -S lsb_release 
lsb-release: /usr/bin/lsb_release
lsb-release: /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz
lsb-release: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
lsb-release: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lsb_release.py
```

Also found and verified  `lsb-release` from [software.opensuse.org](https://software.opensuse.org/package/lsb-release)

so, the package is **`lsb-release`**, And command to install:

```
zypper install lsb-release
```

For more information about How to install package/software on openSUSE, visit: [Installing Software](http://opensuse-guide.org/installpackage.php).